# tolerance in cloze questions

Tags: r, r-exams

I would like to understand how to set up correctly tolerance bounds in cloze questions containing numeric and schoice questions.

Here is an example, where I have a schoice question followed by two numeric questions and I would like the tolerance bounds for the two numeric questions to be 0 and 0.01, respectively.

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=

type <- c("schoice", "num", "num")
solutions <- explanations <- rep(list(""), 3)


solutions[[1]] <- c(1, 0, 0)
solutions[[2]]<- 0
solutions[[3]] <- 1/8

solutions[type=="num"] explanations[type=="schoice"] <-
lapply(solutions[type=="schoice"], function(x) ifelse(x, "True", "False")) 

solutions[type=="schoice"] <- lapply(solutions[type=="schoice"], mchoice2string)


tol <- 0

tol[2]<- 0.01

@


\begin{question}


What is the capital of Italy?  

\begin{answerlist} 
\item Rome \item Madrid \item Berlin 
\item  How many people live in a empty house?  
\item Compute 1/8. (tolerance: \Sexpr{tol[2]}). 
\end{answerlist}


\end{question}




%% META-INFORMATION 
%% \extype{cloze} 
%% \exclozetype{\Sexpr{paste(type, collapse = "|")}} 
%% \exsolution{\Sexpr{paste(solutions, collapse = "|")}} 
%% \exname{prova_tol} 
%% \extol{\Sexpr{paste(tol, collapse = "|")}}
```

As a result, I obtain instead a tolerance of 0.01 for the first numeric question and of zero for the second one. Indeed, this is the "question text" that I get in Moodle:

> What is the capital of Italy?
>
> a. {1:MULTICHOICE_V:%100%Rome~%0%Madrid~%0%Berlin}
>
> b. How many people live in a empty house? {1:NUMERICAL:=0:0.01}
>
> c. Compute 1/8. (tolerance: 0.01). {1:NUMERICAL:=0.125:0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you need to specify one `extol` element for every cloze element, even if the cloze elements are not numeric. So with

```
\exclozetype{schoice|num|num}
```

you would need

```
\extol{0|0|0.1}
```

to get the tolerances 0 and 0.1 for the two num elements.

But I agree that your approach would also make sense. I'll have a look at whether it is possible to support both - and issue a warning if the number of tolerances is not one of the number of all elements or of all num elements, respectively.